How to correctly fix TS2345 compilation error in TypeScript 4.7 to 4.8 upgrade
Our code was compiling and running fine under TypeScript 4.7.4, but we are now trying to upgrade from TypeScript 4.7.4 to a newer version. We are seeing an error when compiling on 4.8.4 that was not present when compiling with 4.7.4.
I have isolated the error into its own small code-snippet. Compiling with 4.8.4 (or any newer version of TypeScript) we get an error like this:
src/example2.ts:19:62 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, BasicValue>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{}'.

19         typeof value === 'object' && areFieldsValid(PFields, value, isValidPField);
                                                                ~~~~~

This sounds similar to, but not the same as, a description of a breaking change in the release notes for TypeScript 4.8 - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#unconstrained-generics-no-longer-assignable-to
Our reproducible example code looks like:
export interface PNode { 
    'text'?: string
}

export const PFields = ['text'];

export type DefinedBasicValue = number | boolean | string | Array<BasicValue> | {} | {
    [key: string]: BasicValue
    [key: number]: BasicValue
}

export type BasicValue = undefined | DefinedBasicValue


/**
 * Take any object, value, undefined, or null, and determine if it is a PNode
 */
export const isPNode = (value?: {}): value is PNode =>
        typeof value === 'object' && areFieldsValid(PFields, value, isValidPField)

export function areFieldsValid(fields: string[], value: Record<string, BasicValue>, ...validations: ((field: string, value: BasicValue) => boolean)[]): boolean {
    return true
}

export const isValidPField = (field: string, value: BasicValue): boolean => true

The error is with the value argument in the function call (on line 19): areFieldsValid(PFields, value, isValidPField).
Please can someone help us to understand why this is ok in TS 4.7, but not in newer versions? Also what would be the "best" / "correct" way to go about fixing such errors? We want to avoid "workarounds" please.
Playground using v4.7.4 with no error
Playground using v4.8.4 with the error
Playground with the current version (v5.4.5) with the error

Is there any reason you can't/shouldn't update isPNode to use value?: Record<string, BasicValue>?

@T.J.Crowder Would that still mean that isPNode can be still be called against any object, primitive, array, type, null, or undefined value? We want to be able to execute an isPNode check against anything that might exist out there...

@adamretter primitives are not assignable to Record

VLAZ has explained the change in v4.8, but the typeguards they've shown don't prevent isPNode from passing primitives to areFieldsValid, which would make me uncomfortable.
You've said you want to call it with any value, including primitives (which would make it return false). To my mind, that's a valid use of any, but you could also use unknown. I'm not bothered by using any in this situation because isPNode is a type predicate, presumably used at some kind of boundary between the untyped world and the typed world (otherwise you wouldn't need to allow primitives, since it will always return false for them), and you've said you literally want it to allow any value. But if you follow the "no explicit any" rule or work in a shop that does, you can use unknown or {} | null as well, they just require adding a type assertion.
any:
export const isPNode = (value?: any): value is PNode =>
    typeof value === 'object' &&
    !!value &&
    areFieldsValid(PFields, value, isValidPField);

Playground link
Note I added a && !!value to weed out null, since typeof null is "object").
unknown:
export const isPNode = (value?: unknown): value is PNode =>
    typeof value === 'object' &&
    !!value &&
    areFieldsValid(PFields, value as Record<string, BasicValue>, isValidPField);

Playground link
Again note the && !!value to handle null. I don't think you can avoid the type assertion there, though I could be mistaken. I'm still getting used to unknown.
{} | null
Finally, you could also use value?: {} | null, although I think that's basically just another way to write value?: any. The same implementation as the unknown solution works with that type as well:
export const isPNode = (value?: {} | null): value is PNode =>
    typeof value === 'object' &&
    !!value &&
    areFieldsValid(PFields, value as Record<string, BasicValue>, isValidPField);

Playground link

Thanks @t-j-crowder I went with the unknown solution as I felt that was the best solution for our issue.

Reason
In TypeScript 4.8 there were changes made to control flow analysis and how the {} type works. There are two changes in particular that lead to this behaviour:

Intersecting T & {} simplifies to T now. This is an optimisation in some case, for example NonNullable has been redefined as type NonNullable<T> = T & {}; which then allows for the simplification NonNullable<NonNullable<T>> == NonNullable<T>.
typeof x === "object intersects the current known type of x with object | null.

The result of both together that with value is {} | undefined the code typeof value === 'object produces ({} | undefined) & (object | null) which then simplifies to object (undefined and null are eliminated, leaving {} & object)
function foo(x?: {}) {
    x; // {} | undefined
    if (typeof x === "object") {
        x; // object
    }
}

Playground Link
This is an issue in this case because object is not assignable to any of the Record types. This does follow because object simply means "non-primitive value" which is a wider type than what Record<TKey, TValue> represents which is an object with indexable key-value pairs. Or in other words, some sort of map/dictionary. Not all objects work like that, therefore you cannot "downcast" safely. For more on object see Difference between 'object' ,{} and Object in TypeScript

Release notes for 4.8
Relevant pull request


It looks like the OP wants to allow isPNode to be called with any value, including primitives (for which it would return false). How would you approach that?

Yes, exactly @T.J.Crowder I do want to call isPNode on any value and have it simply return true or false.

@adamretter - To my mind, that's a valid use of any (I humbly believe there are some): export const isPNode = (value?: any): value is PNode => typeof value === 'object' && !!value && areFieldsValid(PFields, value, isValidPField) (note I added a && !!value to weed out null, since typeof null is "object"). Or unknown: export const isPNode = (value?: unknown): value is PNode => typeof value === 'object' && !!value && areFieldsValid(PFields, value as Record<string, BasicValue>, isValidPField). But VLAZ will probably have a better suggestion.

I've updated. If basically anything should be allowed, then the first approach covers that. Everything except null is accepted. The second one is more restrictive.

@VLAZ - I'm struggling to apply the first solution to isPNode. It shows narrowing {} | undefined, but what the OP needs is a test that, if true, lets them pass the result to something expecting Record<string, BasicValue>.

@T.J.Crowder I guess only Boolean doesn't work, the rest do: https://tsplay.dev/wjoz6N

@VLAZ - From a type perspective I guess, but areFieldsValid expects an object for value. Granted, the implementation isn't shown, but those will all pass through true (for instance) to it, which seems like a source of bugs to me. I realize autoboxing will apply if they do things like value["some prop name"], but... :-)

@T.J.Crowder My attention is very split today. I've written the answer and only glanced at the comments for less than a minute at a time to update stuff. So, I'm not sure what is wrong. My understanding is that isPNode = (value?: {}): value is PNode was the original signature and OP was happy with it, but the 4.8 upgrade made it not work. Is that not the case?

@VLAZ - Yes, but their original solution checked that value was an object before passing it to areFieldsValid, which makes sense since areFieldsValid accepts a Record<string, BasicValue> (an object type). The solutions above change the guard so that it prevents undefined instead -- which means it will start passing primitives to areFieldsValid. I don't understand why TypeScript allows that (it doesn't allow this), and separately passing primitives to a function that doesn't expect them seems like a source of...

...bugs to me. Not trying to give you a hard time (far from it!), just trying to understand things and find a good solution that works in v4.8+ and doesn't pass primitives to a function whose signature disallows them.


Everything except null is accepted
@VLAZ I did write that I wanted to also be able to pass null. So I am afraid that we must handle that too!


@adamretter - Just FWIW, as far as I can tell, your original code didn't allow null. (I did allow for null in my answer, because the comment in the code said it should be allowed.)

@adamretter then {} would have never worked. The type is a lower-bound for what properties are allowed. And empty means "value with any properties is allowed". This includes primitives. There are only two values that are disallowed by the type {}: null and undefined. The call isPNode(null); has never been allowed in 4.7 or before (3.3 is the oldest version on the TS playground). I'm puzzled how you came to have a problem with the change to how {} is handled if that was never a valid type for your use-case.

Okay it looks like I was mistaken and that we never allowed null previously. Apologies, I am quite new to TypeScript. Regardless, I do think it is a good idea to allow null here.

@adamretter At this point I don't understand what is being asked for here. You wanted to understand the error and how to fix it, which I provided an explanation for and how it would work as before or stricter. I'm told now that it should 1. have a different signature 2. also filter out primitives which it didn't before. I've removed the solutions section, since it doesn't seem to match. I don't know what a proper solution would look like - how much of the type guard function should be changed. and what the end result should do.

@VLAZ - "2. also filter out primitives which it didn't before." Before it had typeof value === 'object' && areFieldsValid(PFields, value, isValidPField) which filters out primitives, returning false for any primitive value rather than passing it on to areFieldsValid.

I want to thank you for your comments @VLAZ and explanation it did help. I am sorry if my question was confusing. Your explanations did help me get to the answer, but ultimately I felt that the answer from @t-j-crowder which used uknown and as Record... was the answer I needed. Thank you again.
